# Need to get the sum from the joined column in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

Need to get the sum from the selected column in linq query

I grouped the tables and got the records according to the group, but in that I need to get the sum of marks obtained by candidate.

```
(from subCategory in NIS_SUBCATEGORies
group subCategory by subCategory.ID into sg

    join category in NIS_CATEGORies on sg.FirstOrDefault().CategoryId equals category.ID
    join question in NIS_QUESTIONS on sg.FirstOrDefault().ID equals question.SubcategoryId
    join nisAnswer in NIS_QUESTION_ANSWERS on question.ID equals nisAnswer.QuestionId
    join userAnswer in NIS_USER_ANSWERS on new 
    {
        X1 = nisAnswer.QuestionId,
        X2 = nisAnswer.IsCorrectAnswer
    } equals new
    {
        X1 = userAnswer.QuestionId,
        X2 = true
    }                                  
    join nisUser in NIS_USERS on userAnswer.UserId equals nisUser.Id
    select new 
    {
        SubCategoryName = sg.FirstOrDefault().Name,
        CategoryId = category.ID,
        FirstName = nisUser.FirstName,
        LastName = nisUser.LastName,
        MobileNumber = nisUser.UserName,
        userMarks =  question.Marks
    }
).Distinct()
```

I need Sum from the below column

```
userMarks =  question.Marks
```

Something like

```
userMarks =  Sum(question.Marks)
```

Comment: `userMarks =  question.Marks.Sum()`

Comment: @AAA: This code is not working giving an error message

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @AAA:'int' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Sum(System.Linq.IQueryable<int>)' has some invalid arguments

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>'

Comment: That means `Marks` is an int. How then can you sum that? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your model correctly, but I think you would be better starting with your Users Answers and join the other tables from there

eg

```
(from userAnswer in NIS_USER_ANSWERS
    where userAnswer.IsCorrectAnswer == true
    join nisUser     in NIS_USERS          on userAnswer.UserId       equals nisUser.ID                                                                   
    join question    in NIS_QUESTIONS      on userAnswer.QuestionId   equals question.ID   
    join subCategory in NIS_SUBCATEGORies  on question.SubcategoryId  equals subCategory.ID 

    group new { userAnswer, question } by new
    {
        SubCategoryName  = subCategory.Name,
        subCategory.CategoryId,
        nisUser.FirstName,
        nisUser.LastName,
        nisUser.MobileNumber,            
    }
    into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.SubCategoryName,
        g.Key.CategoryId,
        g.Key.FirstName,
        g.Key.LastName,
        g.Key.MobileNumber,
        userMarks = g.Sum(a => a.question.Marks)
    }
)
```

You would need to check all the joins as they may not be correct.

Note, this would be a lot simpler if your model is defined correctly with navigation properties, as you would not need to write the joins manually and that removes the possibility of writing them incorrectly.

For example, your query might be

```
(from userAnswer in NIS_USER_ANSWERS
    where userAnswer.IsCorrectAnswer == true

    group userAnswer by new
    {
        SubCategoryName  = userAnswer.Question.SubCategory.Name ,
        userAnswer.Question.SubCategory.CategoryId,
        userAnswer.User.FirstName,
        userAnswer.User.LastName,
        userAnswer.User.MobileNumber,            
    }
    into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.SubCategoryName,
        g.Key.CategoryId,
        g.Key.FirstName,
        g.Key.LastName,
        g.Key.MobileNumber,
        userMarks = g.Sum(a => a.Question.Marks)
    }
)
```